# How to create an Ansible inventory with dict variables

Tags: ansible, inventory

I am looking to create an ansible inventory with dict varibles.

I am looking for an inventory something like below

```
[leafs]
leaf01 ansible_host=10.16.10.11 ansible_network_os=vyos ansible_user=my_vyos_user res_tags={Owner:Ted, Role: Support, Environment: Dev }
```

Is it actually possible to use dict in inventory?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Is it actually possible to use dict in inventory?"*

A: Yes. It is possible. Use YAML format if you have problems with INI format. See [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups). For example

```
$ cat hosts
leafs:
  hosts:
    leaf:
      ansible_host: 10.16.10.11
      ansible_network_os: vyos
      ansible_user: my_vyos_user
      res_tags: {Owner: Ted, Role: Support, Environment: Dev}
```

The playbook

```
- hosts: leafs
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: res_tags
```

gives

```
ok: [leaf] => {
    "res_tags": {
        "Environment": "Dev", 
        "Owner": "Ted", 
        "Role": "Support"
    }
}
```